# Renaming columns in csv by column index

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a csv file:

```
visitIp        userId   idSite
128.227.50.161   a        35
24.222.206.154   a        35
10.12.0.1        a        35
10.12.0.1        a        35
10.12.0.1        a        35
24.222.206.154   a        35
```

I want to rename the column in the third index that is 'idSite' to just Id. The reason I want to do it by index is that there might be other csvs that have different column names in the 3rd column. So i need to rename by index as not by name. This is what i tried. But it does not seem to be working:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv',dtype='unicode')
df1 = df.rename(columns = {'df.ix[:,2:3]':'id'})
print df1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the column setting the `.columns.values[2]` value directly:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', dtype='unicode', delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns.values[2] = "id"
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          visitIp userId  id
0  128.227.50.161      a  35
1  24.222.206.154      a  35
2       10.12.0.1      a  35
3       10.12.0.1      a  35
4       10.12.0.1      a  35
5  24.222.206.154      a  35
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a better way to do this using df.rename; but this will work:

```
df['Id'] = df['idSite'] 
df = df.drop('idSite', axis=1)
```

you should be able to find a solution in another thread